# How to send a json file to a spring controller?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc

After validating all inputs from a form, I try to send a JSON to a controller (Spring-MVC Framework). But, I've been getting empty data objects all the time.

Here's my `.js` file

```
/**
 * 
 */

$(document).ready(function() {
 alert('Running ... ');
});



function validateForm() {

        var name = document.forms.myform.elements.name.value;
        var email = document.forms.myform.elements.email.value;
        var description = document.forms.myform.elements.description.value;
        var error = 'has-error';
        var ok = 'has-success';

        if (!name || !email || !description) {

          // alert(description);
          if (!description) {
            $('#description_form').addClass(error);
          } else {
            $('#description_form').removeClass(error).addClass(ok);
          }
          if (!name) {
            $('#name_form').addClass(error);
          } else {
            $('#name_form').removeClass(error).addClass(ok);
          }
          if (!email) {
            $('#email_form').addClass(error);
          } else {
            $('#email_form').removeClass(error).addClass(ok);
          }
          return false;
        }

        var frm = $(document.forms.myform);


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/insert',
                data: {
                        name: "Name", 
                        email: "example@abc.com", 
                        desc: "Not a real person" 
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Submission was successful.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                },
                beforeSend: function (data) {
                    console.log('Before sending data ... ');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();

        return true;

}
```

For the controller part, `org.json.JSONObject` library is used:

```
package gac.asr;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void getData(JSONObject json) {
        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }
}
```

When running the application I get the "Running ..." message from the script. But when I try to print the data coming also from the script I get an empty JSON object "{}".

Edit:

Adding the form which calls the validation script.

```
<form:form name="myform" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST" action="/insert">
<!--MORE CODE-->
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create a wrapper to encapsulate all yours attributes. Let's call it MyEntity

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String desc;
    //getters setters
}
```

In your controller just use it

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getData(MyEntity person) {
    System.out.println(person.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you should use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getData(
  @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true,) String name,
  @RequestParam(value = "email", required = true,) String email,
){
  System.out.println(name);
  ...
}
```

Comment: I got a "HTTP Status 400 - Required String parameter 'name' is not present" message